# How can I add close icon to full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add 'close' icon for full calendar  at top right. I can't do this directly. Is there any alternative way?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2017-10-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2017-10-01'
                },              
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2017-10-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2017-10-16T16:00:00'
                },      
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2017-10-12T14:30:00'
                },              
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2017-10-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2017-10-28'
                }
            ]
        });

    });
```

One more thing how can I align all date `td` in same size.Here `td` which contains `events` are larger than normal `td` how can I keep it in same size?

https://jsfiddle.net/5rfbrm9w/

Comment: Does this close just need to clear the calendar container? What do you mean by close?

Comment: yes.`close` icon is just need to close the container.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/5rfbrm9w/2/

Comment: Correct.but I want to add this, next to `october 2017` which means top right corner.

Comment: Cool, I gave you a starting point though. You append the close button after you've created the calendar. The `october` heading has a class you can use as a selector.

Comment: got it.thanks:-) can you give me any idea for my second question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution:

```
$(".fc-right").append('<span class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

First issue:

HTML:

```
<div id='calendar'><div id="close">X</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#calendar {
  position: relative;
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

*And then add the functionality with jQuery.*

Second issue:

CSS:

```
td {
  min-height: 25px;
}
```